# how to create a function that will collect some scope/env information inline of the caller first?

Tags: python

The question can be illustrated using a simple example, The `mainline.py` calls a function in `prettyprint.py`:

```
# in mainline.py
from prettyprint import prettyprint
array = list('abc')
prettyprint('array', {**globals(), **locals()})

# in prettyprint.py
def prettyprint(codestring, env):
    print( eval(codestring, env) )
```

The question is, is there anything I can do in `def prettyprint` to ask `prettyprint` to collect the caller's scope information `{**globals(), **locals()}` implicitly, so that:

- I don't have to type `{**globals(), **locals()}` everytime I call
  `prettyprint`. I will be always collecting that.
- In my `mainline.py`, calling `prettyprint` can be simplified by only typing
  `prettyprint('array')`

Comment: Call `inspect.currentframe()` and you can dig the info you want out of the caller's stack frame.

Comment: @kindall thanks for the suggestion, but having trouble to ( 1 ) unpack the `f_locals` `frame` ( 2 ) converting a `frame` into a `dict` ( 3 ) what is a `frame` in python, can't even google that thing...

Comment: @ugn "Stack frame" is a generic term; i.e., not specific to python. It means the information associated with a specific function call such as the name of the function, the arguments passed to it, etc. In most languages, and on most CPUs, each function/method call creates a new "stack frame". That's what `inspect.currentframe()` gives you. When the function returns the current stack frame goes away and the previous stack frame becomes active again.